# Changing a struct on the stack inside function

Tags: c, struct, stack

I am working through the *Learn C the Hard Way* and I am currently stuck on the [extra credit exercise number 16](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html).

I am currently trying to adapt their code and making the struct on the stack instead of the heap but my code is giving me segmentation fault and I am unsure why or how to proceed. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

void Person_create(struct Person p,char *name,int age,int height,int weight)
{
    p.name = name;
    p.age = age;
    p.height = height;
    p.weight = weight;
}

void Person_print(struct Person who)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", who.name);
    printf("\tAge: %d\n", who.age);
    printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who.height);
    printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who.weight);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // make two people structures
    struct Person joe;
    struct Person frank;
    Person_create(
            joe,"Joe Alex",32,64,140);

    Person_create(
            frank,"Frank Blank",20,72,180);

    // print them out
    Person_print(joe);
    Person_print(frank);

    // make everyone age 20 years and print them again
    joe.age += 20;
    joe.height -= 2;
    joe.weight += 40;
    Person_print(joe);

    frank.age += 20;
    frank.weight += 20;
    Person_print(frank);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C uses pass by value. `Person_create()` doesn't modify the struct you pass in – it modifies a local copy.

Comment: Go back and read [chapter 4](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html) on using Valgrind.  It'll help you find the issue.  In addition, skip ahead and read to [chapter 31](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex31.html) on debugging.

Comment: I've just read the question, the idea here is to not use pointers at all so the Person_create should return the structure and you shouldn't be passing a pointer to it as an argument. You can create a local instance of the structure and return it as it will pass a copy back to the caller (so no refering to stack variables that heve been destroyed). Apart from that, it looks OK but doing strings without using pointers will be tricky (and I don't think they want you to try either).

Comment: I should add that this isn't really good practice, using pointers (or references!) is a better way to do it, but hopefully you'll learn something useful here.

Comment: Maybe instead of `void Person_create(....` use `struct Person Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight) { return (struct Person ) { name, age, height, weight } ; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code produces errors at runtime is that C passes `struct`s by value, meaning that the following assignments inside `Person_create` have no effect:

```
p.name = name;
p.age = age;
p.height = height;
p.weight = weight;
```

This makes no changes to `joe` and `frank` inside `main()`, leading to undefined behavior on printing, because `name` data member of the `struct Person` remains uninitialized.

In order to fix this problem, pass `struct Person` by pointer, and apply `->` operator in place of `.` operator:

```
void Person_create(struct Person *p,char *name,int age,int height,int weight)
{
    p->name = name;
    p->age = age;
    p->height = height;
    p->weight = weight;
}
...
Person_create(&joe, "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);
//            ^ Pass an address
```

> It is asking for me to not use pointers or malloc, and says as advice to look into creating a struct on the stack

Your code already creates the `struct`s on the stack. If you would like to get rid of pointers completely, change `Person_create` to *return` a new person, like this:

```
struct Person Person_create(char *name,int age,int height,int weight) {
    struct Person p;
    p.name = name;
    p.age = age;
    p.height = height;
    p.weight = weight;
    return p;
}
...
joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);
```

Comment: I understand, perhaps I might have misunderstood what the extra credit was asking for but I think it wants me to get away from the using pointers like that.

Comment: @Amir Are you sure? Or maybe it just want you to do that without dynamic allocation?

Comment: It is asking for me to not use pointers or malloc, and says as advice to look into creating a struct on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Define finction `Person_create` the following way

```
void Person_create(struct Person *p, char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    p->name = name;
    p->age = age;
    p->height = height;
    p->weight = weight;
}
```

and call it like

```
Person_create( &joe, "Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140 );
```

A more sophisticated approach is the following

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//...

void Person_create(struct Person *p, const char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    size_t n = strlen( name );
    p->name = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy( p->name, name );
    p->age = age;
    p->height = height;
    p->weight = weight;
}
```

However in this case you should remember to free the allocated memory when the object of the structure leaves its scope.

Comment: you can use `strdup` to copy strings. That's standard and less liable to off by one errors and suchlike

Comment: @Tom Tanner strdup is not a C standard function. It is a POSIX function.

Comment: Nice `const` catch. +1  Suggest also: `size_t sz = strlen(name)+1; p-name = memcpy(malloc(sz), name, sz);`

Comment: @chux A similar record could be written using strcpy: p->name = strcpy( malloc( sz ), name );

Comment: Nice, could even the use `p->name = strcpy(malloc( strlen(name)+1), name );` but that becomes a bit unreadable.   In my experience, I found `memcpy()` to be significantly faster that `strcpy()` and worth coding that way.  [YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        char *name;
        int age;
        int height;
        int weight;
}Person;

void Person_print(Person who)
{
        printf("Name: %s\n", who.name);
        printf("\tAge: %d\n", who.age);
        printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who.height);
        printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who.weight);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        Person joe= {"Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140};
        Person frank={"Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140};

        printf("Joe is at memory location: %p\n", &joe);
        Person_print(joe);

        printf("Frank is at memory location: %p\n", &frank);
        Person_print(frank);

        joe.age += 20;
        joe.height -= 2;
        joe.weight += 40;
        Person_print(joe);

        frank.age += 20;
        frank.weight += 20;
        Person_print(frank);

        return 0;
}
```

Typedef the struct called 'Person', then you don't have to use 'Person create'.